# Flutter compile time Platform check

Tags: flutter, performance, dart, compilation

if you use `dart:io`'s `Platform.isIOS; Platform.isAndroid;` or the `kIsWeb` constant is that a runtime or a compile time check? It is absolutely critical that it is a compile time check because I need the app to be minimal in size. I know you can do some complex/fancy checks with external packages and all that like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61677387/14865757), but I would love to keep it simple if else statements. Also can someone provide documentation or articles  so that I can read up on it.

Answer (score 0):

They differ. From [`Platform`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Platform-class.html)'s documentation:

> Information about the environment in which the current program **is running**.

However [kIsWeb](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/kIsWeb-constant.html) specifies:

> A constant that is true if the application **was compiled** to run on the web.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72236603/do-apps-built-with-flutter-suffer-from-dead-code) the TreeShaker will remove code it can detect in compile time that is not reachable - so `kIsWeb` parts can effect the build while `Platform` cannot. Also note the answer mentions tree shaking will only be performed on Release versions, so make sure you test correctly.